# How to merge two tables based on id and then get a date value from the second table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have two tables

```
Table 1 - student_id number, class_type varchar2(10), class_time date, attn_time date.

Table 2 - student_id number, attendance varchar2(5), attn_recorded_time date.
```

I am generating a report here where I need to print all the values from table 1 and an additional info or matching value recorded_time from table 2 based on certain conditions.

```
  SELECT a.student_id ,
  a.class_type,
  a.class_time,
  b.attn_recorded_time
FROM student_details a
LEFT JOIN attendance_details b
ON a.student_id    = b.student_id
WHERE a.class_time > b.attn_recorded_time
AND b.attn_recorded_time BETWEEN a.class_time AND (a.class_time - 1/24)
ORDER BY a.student_id,
  a.class_time;
```

So the condition here is the class_time should always be greater than the attendance time and between the class_time and class_time - 1 hr.

I am trying to achieve the same using a merge statement

```
merge INTO student_details a USING attendance_details b ON (a.student_id = b.student_id)
WHEN matched THEN 
update set a.attn_time = b.attn_recorded_time
where b.attn_recorded_time between a.class_time and a.class_time- 1/24;
```

Data for table 1

```
Student_id   class_type  class_time            attn_time
   1203       English    2018-09-10 11:00:00   
   1203       Maths      2018-09-10 11:30:00
```

Data for table 2

```
Student_id    attendance    attendance_recorded_time
1203             Y          2018-09-10 10:00:00
1203             Y          2018-09-10 11:00:00
1203             Y          2018-09-10 08:00:00
1203             Y          2018-09-10 09:00:00
```

Required data

```
Student_id     class_type  class_time             attn_time         
1203             English   2018-09-10 11:00:00    2018-09-10 10:00:00
1203             Maths     2018-09-10 11:30:00    2018-09-10 11:00:00
```

even though there are multiple data available for the same student_id 1203, I need to retrieve the latest attendance_recorded_time based on the class_time

How to achieve the above output and what am I doing wrong here?

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `where` condition put lower value first (in `between`) or do it like here:

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/OCVV4859)</sup>**

```
select * 
    from student_details a
    join attendance_details b using (student_id)
    where class_time - interval '1' hour <= attn_recorded_time 
      and attn_recorded_time < class_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below to get the desired output.

```
SELECT t.your_column
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT a.Student_id,
    MAX(b.attendance_recorded_time),
    a.class_type,
    MAX(a.class_time)
  FROM student_details
  LEFT JOIN b
  ON a.student_id    = b.student_id
  WHERE a.class_time > b.attn_recorded_time
  AND b.attn_recorded_time BETWEEN a.class_time AND (a.class_time - 1/24)
  GROUP BY attendance_recorded_time,
    class_time
  ORDER BY a.student_id,
    a.class_time
  ) ;
```